# R - How to make an expression containing a string and a dynamic variable bold in r/ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression, ggpmisc

I am trying to make multiple facetted plots in r/ggplot2 that show R^2 and P values generated using the ggpmisc package, but format each line based on whether the P-value is below a certain number.
I can successfully do this with a single character, the "R" and "P", but I cannot get the superscript 2 in R^2, the equal sign, or the value itself formatted. Possibly complicating things is that I'd like the value rounded to 3 decimal places, which I can do, but again I can't get the format to apply. Here is the problem code and output:

edit: added `my.formula <- y ~ x` line of code at beginning of code to make it work.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpmisc)

##edit: I left out this very important line previously (Thank you for pointing this out)
my.formula <- y ~ x  

##data (sorry for all the extra whitespace, have never known how to remove this
ex1 <- structure(list(time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
                                       .Label = c("early", "late"), class = "factor"),
      x = c(0.321386372587633, 0.321386372587633, 0.321386372587633, 0.321386372587633, 0.321386372587633, 
            0.344034242910647, 0.344034242910647, 0.344034242910647, 0.344034242910647, 0.344034242910647,
            0.339242868568382, 0.339242868568382, 0.339242868568382, 0.339242868568382, 0.339242868568382,
            0.319449901768173, 0.319449901768173, 0.319449901768173, 0.319449901768173, 0.319449901768173,
            0.355824915824916, 0.355824915824916, 0.355824915824916, 0.355824915824916, 0.355824915824916, 
            0.343082264957265, 0.343082264957265, 0.343082264957265, 0.343082264957265, 0.343082264957265,
            0.328739896647675, 0.328739896647675, 0.328739896647675, 0.328739896647675, 0.328739896647675,
            0.321470937129300, 0.321470937129300, 0.321470937129300, 0.321470937129300, 0.321470937129300,
            0.329134067099854, 0.329134067099854, 0.329134067099854, 0.329134067099854, 0.329134067099854, 
            0.303929221962009, 0.303929221962009, 0.303929221962009, 0.303929221962009, 0.303929221962009,
            0.318415163880479, 0.318415163880479, 0.318415163880479, 0.318415163880479, 0.318415163880479, 
            0.299444516212376, 0.299444516212376, 0.299444516212376, 0.299444516212376, 0.299444516212376,
            0.343325715822019, 0.343325715822019, 0.343325715822019, 0.343325715822019, 0.343325715822019, 
            0.372169617126390, 0.372169617126390, 0.372169617126390, 0.372169617126390, 0.372169617126390,
            0.370415982484948, 0.370415982484948, 0.370415982484948, 0.370415982484948, 0.370415982484948,
            0.356533513879486, 0.356533513879486, 0.356533513879486, 0.356533513879486, 0.356533513879486,
            0.388973753645327, 0.388973753645327, 0.388973753645327, 0.388973753645327, 0.388973753645327, 
            0.372479078062834, 0.372479078062834, 0.372479078062834, 0.372479078062834, 0.372479078062834,
            0.379030035822541, 0.379030035822541, 0.379030035822541, 0.379030035822541, 0.379030035822541,
            0.407584269662921, 0.407584269662921, 0.407584269662921, 0.407584269662921, 0.407584269662921,
            0.376392901361948, 0.376392901361948, 0.376392901361948, 0.376392901361948, 0.376392901361948, 
            0.317804974338729, 0.317804974338729, 0.317804974338729, 0.317804974338729, 0.317804974338729,
            0.364539393114710, 0.364539393114710, 0.364539393114710, 0.364539393114710, 0.364539393114710,
            0.379058888277380, 0.379058888277380, 0.379058888277380, 0.379058888277380, 0.379058888277380),
      fctr = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L,
                         1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L,
                         1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L,
                         1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L,
                         1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L,
                         1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L),
                       .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor"),
      y = c(4.04851970360232, -0.102591188819765, 3.73315302756709, 0.340504779534468, 0.237913590714702,
            4.06911664322439, -0.0987598497016705, 5.54001741914177, 0.373135505872404, 0.274375656170733, 
            3.67443913261548, -0.0875837250365816, 3.03232358376749, 0.326682585279794, 
            0.239098860243213, 4.17944244767142, -0.0889017722380819, 3.1663639174688, 
            0.242471128656955, 0.153569356418873, 3.21516073180644, -0.0825729432584231, 
            6.99230459733604, 0.41716036686455, 0.334587423606127, 3.9367867766317, 
            -0.100174510844092, 2.72154053689335, 0.328889772105954, 0.228715261261863, 
            3.99729911731233, -0.100900126928578, 4.53860828306993, 0.366724076035605, 
            0.265823949107028, 4.56693109900323, -0.126308420437427, 5.10762234664757, 
            0.395180555800261, 0.268872135362834, 3.51448237912049, -0.0878426078144829, 
            5.65594606508526, 0.248915416023726, 0.161072808209243, 3.1383099374462, 
            -0.0732066492304829, 4.64242423111922, 0.217790427134848, 0.144583777904365, 
            4.49027171118563, -0.113362808190544, 4.80536464343379, 0.36523834263989, 
            0.251875534449346, 3.45497839018504, -0.0846503583222099, 3.45264289330118, 
            0.286441498422214, 0.201791140100004, 2.09894643097191, -0.0181292647706588, 
            3.15649251734621, 0.487077302298916, 0.468948037528257, 2.88011613789647, 
            0.0332011441108258, 2.17243045829905, 0.473011569737156, 0.506212713847982, 
            3.34598270139375, -0.0610926284972918, 2.64804765938524, 0.50849363186508, 
            0.447401003367788, 2.50787708448308, -0.0538689982930191, 2.38574021348553, 
            0.484438241081951, 0.430569242788932, 3.50259329310981, -0.0851862773159426, 
            3.14484623466867, 0.675500135099749, 0.590313857783806, 5.7188910696372, 
            -0.0954071517814848, 0.583392623483105, 0.624411329255129, 0.529004177473644, 
            2.67827579027081, 0.0460408230771886, 2.52145840963862, 0.625860271515617, 
            0.671901094592805, 3.13901517396219, -0.0693247901648161, 3.2356649048874, 
            0.668874437622921, 0.599549647458105, 2.51959640215471, -0.049164926875836, 
            2.23187740027734, 0.492702963511537, 0.443538036635701, 2.42625504206661, 
            0.0874001285858868, 2.8286583173362, 0.545165351011274, 0.632565479597161, 
            3.24857901035993, -0.0689851948115451, 2.91350545205866, 0.569549019107752, 
            0.500563824296207, 2.87505027703064, -0.0611185132088805, 3.2680427609413, 
            0.552874791715019, 0.491756278506139)), row.names = c(NA, -120L), class = "data.frame")


gtest <- ggplot(data = ex1, aes(x, y)) + 
  
  geom_hline(yintercept = -Inf, size = 0.6) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = -Inf, size = 0.8) +
  
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(.06, .1))) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(.1, .6))) +
  
  geom_point() +
  
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = my.formula) +
  
  stat_poly_eq(formula = my.formula,
               output.type = "expression", parse = TRUE,
               aes(label = ifelse(stat(p.value) < 0.05,
                                  paste("bold(R)^2 == ", round(stat(r.squared), digits = 3)), ## at least shows the r.squared value, but I can't get the rest bold
                                  ifelse(stat(p.value) < 0.1,
                                         paste("plain(R)^2 == ", round(stat(r.squared), digits = 3)), ##this contains plain(R) because the default is italic, which I don't want
                                         ""))),
               size = 3,
               label.x = .1,
               label.y = .9) +

  stat_poly_eq(formula = my.formula,
               output.type = "expression", parse = TRUE,
               aes(label = ifelse(stat(p.value) < 0.001,
                                  paste("italic(P) < 0.001"),
                                  ifelse(stat(p.value) < 0.05,
                                         paste("bolditalic(P) == ", round(stat(p.value), digits = 3)),  ##at least shows the p.value, but I can't get the rest bold
                                         paste("italic(P) == ", round(stat(p.value), digits = 3))))),
               size = 3,
               label.x = .1,
               label.y = .76) +
  

theme(axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "black", face = "bold", size = 14, margin = margin(10,0,0,0)),
      axis.title.y = element_blank(),
      legend.key = element_blank(),
      legend.title = element_blank(),
      plot.margin = unit(c(0.2,0.4,.2,.2), "cm"),
      plot.title = element_text(colour = "black", face = "bold", size = 16, hjust = 0.5,margin = margin(0,0,10,0)),
      panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      panel.spacing.x = unit(2, "pt"),
      panel.spacing.y = unit(4, "pt"),
      panel.background = element_blank(),
      strip.placement = "outside",
      strip.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", face = "bold", size = 12, margin = margin(0,0,6,0)),
      strip.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", face = "bold", size = 12, margin = margin(0,3,0,0))) + 
  
  facet_grid(fctr ~ time, scales = "free", switch = "y")

gtest
```

I'm assuming that the `paste()` in `aes(label = ...)` is not base `paste` but rather plotmath `paste`, since `output.type = "expression"` and `parse = TRUE` in the `stat_poly_eq` function call. Futhermore, I've seen numerous examples using `bquote()`, `mtext()`, `substitute()`, etc., instead of `paste()`, but I cannot get them to do what I'd like. Also, I don't think this has anything to do with the ggpmisc package, but rather my lack of understanding of how to format a string with a changing variable using plotmath expressions.

Here is what I generate with the code above. It's hard to see, but the R and P are in bold in panels (early, d) and (early, e), as they should be:
[image: only R and P fomatted]

And here is what I'd like to see, with the entire line in bold:
[image: whole lines in bold]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please, make sure the example code can be actually run. Please, also use as simple as possible an example and data set. There is no need for 10 panels to demonstrate the problem. StackOverflow works as a store of common knowledge, and minimal reproducible examples will be more useful to future readers of the question plus answers.

Comment: I can anyway give some hints. 

Before parsing you are dealing with character strings, so `paste()` is base R's. It is used to assemble a character string that can be parsed into an expression (hence `parse = TRUE`, indicates to 'ggplot2' to call R's `parse()` on the labels). The syntax of expressions is not straightforward but flexible. `help("plotmath")` should give you an idea. An alternative is to pass `output.type = "markdown"` to `stat_poly_eq()` and set `geom = "richtext"` after loading package 'ggtext'.

Comment: @Pedro, thanks for pointing out my error--I added my.formula to the beginning of the example code.

Comment: I do not understand why you do not want the R in R^2 to be in italics. I have italics as default in 'gpmisc' as this is the accepted style used for all parameters when typesetting of mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 1):

`bolditalic()` and `bold()` work like functions, applying the formatting to their argument. So, the code below should do what you want. I haven't tested this on your example as it does not run as is.

```
paste("bolditalic(P) == bold(\"", round(stat(p.value), digits = 3), "\")")
```

We need to enclose the number in quotation marks for `bold()` to apply to it. These quotation marks need to be escaped as `\"` so that they are recognized as part of the character string. R's expressions are so that numbers and Greek symbols are never typeset as bold. So, by including embedded quotation marks when the text is parsed the numbers are seen as character strings rather than numeric constants. So the key question here is how to format numbers as bold in R plotmath expressions.