# How to set the dynamic part of title as bold in a quarto document rendered as html?

Tags: html, r, title, quarto, bold

How to set only the dynamic part of the title specified in the YAML (params$mytitle in the minimal example below) as bold in the rendered HTML? Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68168308/r-how-to-make-an-expression-containing-a-string-and-a-dynamic-variable-bold-in), but did not work.

```
---
params:
  mytitle: "title1"
title: "`r paste('this is',params$mytitle)`"
format: html
editor: visual
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
---
params:
  mytitle: "title1"
title: "this is **{{< meta params.mytitle >}}**"
format: html
editor: visual
---
```

to inject the parameter and make it even more bold. I see this output:
[image]